# Perl retrieve Unix session ID and session leader

Tags: perl

I need to determine the session ID of the current process and the session leader. I see that the [POSIX](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/ext/POSIX/lib/POSIX.pod) module implements ["setsid"](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/ext/POSIX/lib/POSIX.pod#setsid) but not ["getsid"](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getsid.2.html). Is there any way to grab this information in Perl?

Thanks!

Comment: Your original question was fine, but it contained the phrase "trying to find a Perl module", which causes some people to reflexively vote to close the question as "off-topic: looking for a software recommendation". So I edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the builtin [`syscall`](http://metacpan.org/pod/perlfunc#syscall) function

```
require 'syscall.ph';
$sid = syscall(SYS_getsid, $process_id);
```

Comment: This is what I needed. I just had to put "&SYS_getsid" instead of "SYS_getsid" in the "syscall". Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There's a `getsid` in [POSIX::2008](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/POSIX-2008/lib/POSIX/2008.pod#getsid):

> **getsid**
>
> sid = getsid(pid);
>
> *pid* defaults to 0.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [FFI::Platypus](https://metacpan.org/pod/FFI::Platypus) to easily create a Perl interface to such a function with libffi. This one is nice and simple, since it just takes one integer and returns one integer, but I still like to add more Perlish argument and error handling, which FFI::Platypus's attach method allows.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use FFI::Platypus;
use Carp 'croak';
use feature 'say';

my $ffi = FFI::Platypus->new;
$ffi->lib(undef);

$ffi->attach(getsid => ['int'] => 'int' => sub {
  my $xsub = shift;
  my $rc = $xsub->(@_ ? $_[0] : 0);
  croak "$!" if $rc < 0;
  return $rc;
});

say getsid();
say getsid(0);
say getsid($$);
say getsid(1);
say getsid(-1);
```

Output:

```
3276
3276
3276
1
No such process at ...
```